# Filter multiple condition - reactor Flux/Mono filterWhen()

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor, webflux

I am using Mono's `filterWhen()` with multiple conditions like below but don't know how to implement the correct way.

```
Mono.just("a").filterWhen(item -> conditionA && conditionB)...
// or Mono.just("a").filterWhen(item -> conditionA || conditionB)...

// both is reactive call
Mono<Boolean> conditionA(String a) {
     return webClient.call(....).map(Boolean);//sample return Boolean here}
Mono<Boolean> conditionB(String a) {
     return webClient.call(....).map(Boolean);//sample return Boolean here}
```

When use conditionA && conditionB, is it imediately return when conditionA (or conditionB) return false?

Also when use conditionA || conditionB, is it imediately return when conditionA (or conditionB) return true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operators `Flux#all` and `Flux#any` are what you are looking for.

First, merge the responses to a `Flux` of `Boolean` and use `Flux#all` to emit a single boolean true if *all* responses are evaluated to true:

```
Flux.merge(conditionA(), conditionB()).all(condition -> condition)
```

In this way, if `conditionA` is `false` the value `false` is emitted without waiting for the `contitionB` to be evaluated.

As a side note, `Flux.merge` subscribes to the publishers eagerly (all publishers are subscribed together). If you like to execute the conditions sequentially use `Flux.concat` instead.

Comment: I got it, thank you very much.